# python how to create a directory with timestamp in current directory and move all the files from current directory to newtimestamp directory

Tags: python-2.7

current directory has files
/home/ec2/files
abc
def
ghi

want to create a directory using nTime below and move all the files to /home/ec2/files/"nTime"
now = datetime.datetime.today()
   nTime = now.strftime(format)

Answer (score 1):

First you need create the folder in source folder, then loop all files in source folder, move them to the created dest folder. Below is example:

```
import datetime
import shutil
import os
now = datetime.datetime.today() 
nTime = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
source = '/home/ec2/files'
dest = os.path.join(source+nTime)
if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest) #creat dest dir

source_files = os.listdir(source)
for f in source_files:
    source_file = os.path.join(source,f)
    if os.path.isfile(source_file): #check if source file is a file not dir
        shutil.move(source_file,dest) #move all only files (not include dir) to dest dir
```